# Where's the font setting for folders in the Package Explorer?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I'm talking about Eclipse (3.5 = Galileo), running under Kubuntu 9.10 and I have the Subversive plugin.

I've been moved from Gnome-Ubuntu to Kubuntu, and one side effect was that some fonts are now just too tiny to read.

File names in the explorer have a decent size, but **folders** are shown in a too-small font, and after having adjusted all the fonts in `General|Appearance|Colors and Fonts` the folders are unchanged.

Maybe I'm just blind. I'd appreciate it if someone could point me to where I can adjust the font for folders in the Package Explorer

Comment: *from Gnome-Ubuntu to Kubuntu* heresy! :)

Comment: @Pascal: I agree. This change was done against my will, and I'm still having a hell of a time adjusting to it. Nothing works like it used to!

Comment: I didn't really mean to troll, this was more a kind of joke, even if *I* prefer gnome :) Should I understand that it's a corporate move BTW? Interesting if it is. Just for the record, I know there was a gtk-qt-engine package in earlier times (to make gtk applications look good under KDE) but this project has been abandoned (no maintainer). So this doesn't really help you but you should maybe dig a bit in this direction.

Comment: Oh, I understood that. This is a bit like the vi/emacs wars. But yeah, at my workplace we used to run on Fedora 6 or so (ancient and using Gnome) and we finally pushed through an upgrade to Ubuntu. But because our Linux "expert" (who submitted the upgrade request on our behalf) prefers KDE, we got Kubuntu. And the admins refused to install both Gnome and KDE or make it switchable, so our group (about 30 people) is now on KDE whether we want it or not. And we ain't got no root. :(

Comment: look http://techtavern.wordpress.com/2008/09/24/smaller-font-sizes-for-eclipse-on-linux/ Excelent!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It'll use the default GTK+ font settings, as Eclipse is a GTK application.  You may have to install Gnome's Appearance preference applet to get a GUI to change it.

Comment: GTK even under K-Ubuntu? I've adjusted the fonts in `System Settings|Appearance|Fonts` too (all of them) but failed to affect that one. :(

Comment: Dang, I gotta learn to READ and THINK! You were absolutely right, and changing that setting gave me instant success. Thank you VERY much!

Comment: See my own answer for details, if anyone is interested.

Comment: for those looking for the same thing on OS X: 1. remove -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts from your Eclipse.app/.../eclipse.ini (partial result) or 2. use [TinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html) (more comprehensive, system-wide result)

Answer (score 6):

Eclipse is supposed to respect the OS settings but it turns out on Mac OS X the default setting for eclipse is to use small Fonts rather than the standard os fonts. On Mac OS X you can change edit the eclipse.ini file and remove `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts` restart eclipse and presto you will find that your package explorer looks brilliant with reasonable sized fonts.

To find the eclipse.ini on a Mac, right click on Eclipse.app, then select "show package contents", then you will find the ini file in Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse.ini

Answer (score 1):

**Feedback on success:**

It seems that in Kubuntu, any fonts not explicitly specified in Eclipse's preferences come from the system. Eclipse is a Gnome app, so its fonts (among other stuff) are controlled by

`System Settings | Appearance | GTK+ Appearance`

...and there I was able to fiddle the fonts to my satisfaction.

My thanks to Andrew Aylett!